# Html bootstrap showing loading text on page load

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, page-loading-message

http://www.silverbladesolutions.com
If I click on any link on the navbar from the home page, LOADING is shown before all the page content.  Sme thing happens on links from the footer.  If I reload the page, everything works fine. This does not happen with links other than from the index.html.

EDIT: Page code = http://pastebin.com/jeiqqJry

Comment: can we see any code or get any more information about the specifics of the error? It's kind of hard to tell without a little more info

Comment: @phouse512 Just go to the page and click on navbar links and for page code Right-click>View source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM found it.  It was some mobile UI thing added from an old version of jquery mobile that we had.  updating all the jquery fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the location of the code that contains the 'loading' section in the html.

When I first click the about button, it takes me to the page, and in the body tag of the page's html, there is this div:

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default ui-loader-fakefix"   style="top: 212.5px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>
    loading
</h1></div>
```

When I refresh the page, that div disappears and leaves only the rest of the body. There is something happening when you click on that about link for the first time, it opens this div along with the rest.

Also another thing I noticed is that on the first click, the class of the entire html page goes to the class 'ui-mobile'. Is this supposed to happen? I think something weird is happening when you first click the link, because when I refresh, that class disappears as well. Is there an external js script that might be affecting the html?

What's the html of the actual 'about.html' file look like?

Comment: ok that makes sense and that was what I was expecting, but for some reason, extra html is being added to the page when you click on that link. Classes are being added, divs are being inserted, and things are changing for reasons that I can't tell. Maybe something in boot-business.js?

Comment: I thought so too but it ended up being our jquery mobile!

Comment: that's what I thought. The 'ui-mobile' class that was being inserted looked very suspicious. Glad it worked out!